# Процессор для валидаторной ноды Polkadot

Tags: железо, blockchain, intel

Хочу собрать валидаторную ноду для стейкинга в Polkadot. В системных требованиях к железу указан процессор intel core 7700k. Возможно ли вместо него использовать intel xeon E5-2650 v2? [официальные требования](https://wiki.polkadot.network/ru-RU/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot)

Мои мысли: Если процесс параллелятся на все ядра, то возможно, что по производительности в данном случае они будут эквиваленты

Comment: какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к метке node.js?

Comment: Я написал "node", а не "node.js". Спасибо за замечание, но это вопрос к ресурсу, я думаю